# Creating then modifying a map by reflection

Tags: go

I have a new type derived from map such:

```
type mapp map[string]interface{}
```

with a small function on it

```
func (c mapp) Set() error {
    // c is nil
    c["a"] = "b"
    return nil
}

type Setter interface {
  Set() error
}

func main() {
    var aa mapp
    out := reflect.ValueOf(&aa)
    s := out.Interface().(Setter)
    s.Set()
}
```

This code works on a struct, why this code fails when it comes to a type of a map?

Here's a playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Z1LFqb6kF7

Many thanks,

Asaf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go maps (and slices) are created via `make`. The equivalent function in `reflect` is [`reflect.MakeMap`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#MakeMap)

```
out := reflect.ValueOf(&aa).Elem()
out.Set(reflect.MakeMap(out.Type()))
s := out.Interface().(Setter)
s.Set()
```

Comment: thanks, still can't change map's content though ? https://play.golang.org/p/wXbVdcykZf

Comment: @asaf000: if you want to modify `aa`, then you need to set it's value. `aa` is nil, so there's nothing there to modify.  https://play.golang.org/p/XWcx5gDPu7